# Windows directory on Linux

Tags: windows, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows directory on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/96534/windows-directory-on-linux)

Dear all,
I have Linux (suse) and Windows (XP) on my system, but my windows files don't appear in the windows directory of linux. I can't see them. What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Are you dual-booting, or running one OS in a virtual machine atop the other?

Comment: exact duplicate (user cross-posted and this one got migrated): http://superuser.com/questions/96534/windows-directory-on-linux