# Windows directory on Linux

Tags: windows, linux, ntfs, suse

I have Linux (suse) and Windows (XP) on my system, but my windows files don't appear in the windows directory of linux. I can't see them. What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Have you mounted them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the Windows Partitions mounted ? Head over to YaST -> Software -> Partitioner. They should look something like this:

[image: Partitioner 1]

[image: Partitioner 2]

---

To make it writable, Click on `fstab options` and ad an entry `umask=000` as shown in the pic

[image: fstab options]

Comment: Dear Sathya, Thanks alot for your attention. I checked it and also I change it's "Fstab Options" to "Mount Read Only" (I saw none of them have been marked) and then my files appeared. Now I can read them, But I can't write in the windows directory on linux. Are there any option among them that give me full permission for write and read. Regards

Comment: @aryan Uncheck the mount readonly - Just browse to the directory it should get mounted. Your fstab options page should look similar to the pic. Don't forget to add the `umask=000` entry

Comment: @Sathya It doesn't work. I faced an error. error code was: -3003

Comment: @aryan - post a screenshot with the full error message

Comment: @Sathya How can I add an image in my comment?

Comment: @aryan Hit PrintScreen, save the image. Upload it to Imageshack ( http://imageshack.us ) Copy the "Direct link" URL and paste it here